# Need help adjusting a diamond shape in Java

Tags: java, loops

I wrote some code that will print a diamond

```
static void printDiamond(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < (size - (i + 1)); a++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        for (int b = 0; b < (i * 2); b++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int a = 0; a < (size - (i + 1)); a++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        for (int b = 0; b < (i * 2); b++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having with the diamond is that it will print double for whatever I input. So, if the user were to input a 6 for the diamond, it should look like this:

```
  XX
 X  X
X    X
X    X
 X  X
  XX
```

With my code, if the user inputs 5, it prints out the following:

```
    XX
   X  X
  X    X
 X      X
X        X
X        X
 X      X
  X    X
   X  X
    XX
```

Instead of printing out 5 rows, it printed out 10. If I input 3, it will print out 6 rows instead of 3. It seems that for my diamond, it is outputting the number that it receives from the user, but then prints out that amount times 2. Is there a way I can half the size of what the `printDiamond` method outputs so it has the correct number of rows?

Comment: You should re-examine your loop conditions - specifically, the outer loops.

Comment: @mike1319 Small bit of advice.  You didn't need to include the box code or output in your question. Questions are better received if they are more concise.

Comment: @MichaelQuatrani Thank you for your suggestion. I edit the box part of the code out so the question is more concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to correct your code by tweaking the loop boundary conditions.  First, you were printing the *top* portion of your diamond with a height of `size` and you were *also* printing the bottom potion with a height of `size`, for a total height of `2*size`.

The other big problem was that you were not handling odd-numbered inputs, as all diamonds were coming out as even number height.  I also corrected this problem.  Have a look at the code below.

```
static void printDiamond(int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)Math.ceil(size/2.0); i++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < (int)Math.ceil(size/2.0) - (i + 1); a++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        for (int b = 0; b < (i * 2); b++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        System.out.println();
    }

    for (int i = (int)Math.floor(size/2.0)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int a = 0; a < (int)Math.ceil(size/2.0) - (i + 1); a++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        for (int b = 0; b < (i * 2); b++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

printDiamond(5);
System.out.print("\n");
printDiamond(6);
```

**Output:**

```
  XX
 X  X
X    X
 X  X
  XX

  XX
 X  X
X    X
X    X
 X  X
  XX
```

Comment: I just tried this code and if I put in an odd number, it will return the number - 1 row. It works with positive numbers but doesn't seem to work when it's odd.

Comment: I don't think his code _ever_ handled the odd number case.  The whole thing needs to be refactored.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Agreed.  I was thinking about making an entirely different method to handle an odd case.  That being said, very cool!  Can you explain how `Math.ceil` and `Math.floor` are working in this case?

Comment: `Math.ceil()` and `Math.floor()` allow you to conditionally _skip_ the widest row of the diamond in the case that the `size` be odd.  In the case of even, you _do_ want to retain the duplicate widest row.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank you for your help, I haven't been introduced to Math.ceil() or Math.floor() so seeing this is as a solution is very cool.